# Design pattern for storing customer specific requirements

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, design-patterns, sql-server-2012

tldr; Looking for a design pattern that is good at handling a variety of requirements customers have on database fields.

Been looking and have not come across anyone with a similar issue, but if I missed one please let me know! Also, I suspect I may be either over-complicating the issue, or trying to do too much at once. Sorry for the wall of text incoming.

Okay, so I am designing a new application in C# for a company I have worked with in the past. I am writing this application to replace the VB6 application they have in place now. This new application's scope will be for the initial information gathering phase.

The company is for roadside assistance; trucks breaking down for companies with big rig trucks. They assist hundreds of customers, and each customer has its own requirements. The company bends over backwards for each customer, and therefore I need to come up with a manageable design to handle these customer specifications. All previously developed applications had in-line "if else" logic for literally hundreds of customers and I still have nightmares about it.

Example:

A user will take a phone call from a customer and collect information, which they input into this application. They will be calling to report an event such as a flat tire. Sometimes the person calling in is the driver. Other times the driver has called the company they work for, and a representative calls to report the incident and request help. Let's focus on a few pieces of information so I may paint the picture.

1. Customer Reference Number
2. Odometer
3. List item

Not every customer requires a reference number. Some customers require a reference number adhere to a certain mask, for example "Reference Number must start with BD-XXX-XXXX-XX" or something similar. Other customers don't even have reference numbers, so there is no point capturing this data (it doesn't exist).

Some customers require an odometer reading of the mileage, some don't.

So you might begin to see my issue. Customer A doesn't need a reference number. Customer B needs a reference number. It's not as simple as NOT NULL vs NULL though, because B also needs their reference number to match an input mask.

Types of requirements:

- Field value must be Greater than/Less than X
- Field must adhere to Input Mask
- Field Not collected at all
- Field Required
- Field Optional
- Field value dictates whether other information must be/must not be
  collected. If one specific field is null, another becomes required

I would like to store customer requirements in the database (SQL) and perhaps be able to load a class with this data that will be able to handle the requirements for the UI portion of the application.

Components of the project are required to be: 
C# Windows app
WCF Service for data (will be used between multiple applications & web)
SQL Server 2012

Comment: It sounds like you need some sort of rules engine to determine what fields are required and if there's any input validation (masks) associated with that field for a given client.  Depending on the complexity, this might be easily represented in a database, with the various fields and/or masks tied to the client key.

Comment: Other than data, is there also different processes?

Comment: @Tim - so keep a list of requirement type, tie it to the field, and assign it to each customer?

Comment: @plalx - there are processes that are happening in the background which look at data and fire off notifications and that sort of thing, but it's not necessarily related. What i'm mainly focusing on here is the initial collection of data from the customer for each event, and making sure the data that is collected is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I believe that these different customers should be represented by a corresponding `class`. If *customer reference* isn't a common property but it's tied to a certain type of *customer*, then you need to use *inheritance*.

A possible good design pattern to work in your scenario is [*Specification pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), which looks as follows:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
      bool IsSatisfiedBy(T someObject);
}
```

I guess you're going to use *dependency injection* with some *inversion of control container framework*, and you'll be able to configure many implementations of `ISpecification<T>`. Once you've already configured them, you should be able to get them filtered by `T`, where `T` will be your *customer* classes.

That is, you'll be able to load a subset of `ISpecification<T>` implementations to check if some *customer* instance fulfills one or more given speficiations designed to check the specific *customer* type.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about using IoC to scrub event data for customer specification issues, but I was looking for a way to avoid creating hundreds of customer classes! I was hoping to put code in place that would not require alteration when customer requirements change. Hopefully just updating SQL would be enough. I think creating one class with specifications in it, loaded on a customer-by-customer basis with requirements info, might do the trick. I just have to come up with a feasible design.

Comment: @Shockwave No problem! You're welcome. Yes, you can go that way too. At the end of the day, specification pattern is very simple but it can be turned into a very powerful tool ;)